# A possible way to initiate a nuclear fusion reaction without a nuclear fission trigger

Tags: thermodynamics, fusion

A few years back I read in either Popular Science or Popular Mechanics about a new kind of high explosive that had an energy density many times higher than the most potent ones previously developed, maybe even orders of magnitude  higher. Is it possible that an armored glass (transparent aluminum) ampule, tightly packed with Lithium Dueteride and Tritium could be placed in an extremely strong cavity that could be crushed by some properly placed explosives. A diamond projectile could be driven into it at the proper instant by another explosive charge to greatly increase both the pressure and temperature, thus potentially making conditions right for a small or controlled fusion reaction. I don't have access to the proper engineering information which is probably classified or the powerful computers needed to run simulations of the process to even know if my idea is even close to being workable. I have in the past carried a top secret clearance while in the USAF. Any comments by people with the proper information base are welcomed and yes, I do understand that scaled up it could be used as a fusion only bomb. I just happen to believe that it would be much more useful as a system to feed a tokamak. Thank you all in advance for all of your input.

Comment: So, are you asking if it will work.

Comment: That is a nuclear wall of text

Comment: *I just happen to believe that it would be much more useful as a system to feed a tokamak* You want to "feed tokamak" with a *bomb*?

Comment: I have +1'd it and will post an answer a little later when I have the time. In short, fusion-fission hybrids do exist, but not in the form that you are imagining. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, the system that you are imagining is a [*nuclear fusion-fission hybrid*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion-fission_hybrid), except for the fact that it is supposed to work in the exact opposite manner as compared to what you have imagined - the tokamak is not powered by a fission bomb here.

The basic idea behind the proposal goes as follows:

Nuclear fission is known to be a popular alternative energy source, and is being used for power generation as well. However, a big problem with fission is the disposal of nuclear waste. The radioactive waste is an environmental hazard and we haven't worked up any reliable method of dealing with it (which could be consistently used for many many years in the future, despite the fact that people keep floating all kinds of exotic solutions).

As is known pretty well, nuclear fusion doesn't have this drawback. Environment is not threatened by any waste here, which is why everyone is hell-bent towards looking at fusion as an alternative energy source for the future, and projects like [ITER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITER) are envisaged. The only problem with nuclear fusion is, we haven't been able to get past what fusion people call the [*break-even condition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_energy_gain_factor), implying that the energy output from a fusion reactor so far hasn't exceeded the energy spent as input. (This is an important point - it is not that fusion isn't achieved in the lab, just that any net energy gain via nuclear fusion alone hasn't been reported yet.) Of course, that continues to be an area of active research.

Now, the way a fusion-fission hybrid is supposed to work is - you juxtapose fission and fusion chambers, and the neutrons generated during the fusion process are targeted at the "waste" produced during the fission process, which includes polonium. This would lead to  polonium fission, which would serve two purposes - your "waste" is disposed off, and you achieve a fission multiplication. Since there is a net energy gain in the fission process (obviously), this fission multiplication leads to a high total energy gain. Of course, the poorer cousin fusion would have a net energy loss as usual, but notice that the net energy gain/loss of the hybrid would be decided by the total energy consumed during fission + fusion, subtracted from the total energy produced during fission + fusion.

Thus, fusion is not an energy generator in this process, but the net energy loss during fusion alone, can be more than compensated by the energy gained during your (multiplied) fission reactions. **It is possible to realize an energy gain in the net cycle!** This is why these hybrids are projected to serve as a viable energy option for the future, more than *just* fission, or *just* fusion.

Of course, it is all too premature right now, and these being put to commercial use could take decades. There are engineering challenges too, e.g. isolation is one such issue (because you are in effect placing a nuclear bomb next to a tokamak, even though not powering one using it!). The schematic of the overall structure looks roughly like this:

[image]

But it is a promising candidate for the future. There are few groups working on it (as you can possibly make out from the linked articles, below).

I will point you towards some informative articles here:

1. [Hans Bethe, about Fusion hybrids, in Physics Today](http://large.stanford.edu/publications/coal/references/docs/bethe.pdf).
2. [A Nature News article](http://www.nature.com/news/2009/090701/pdf/460025a.pdf), where the resurgence of these hybrids is dealt with.
3. This answer posted by me is a result of sitting through a colloquium given once by Prof. Swadesh Mahajan of the Institute of Fusion Studies, UT Austin, where he introduced much of what is written above. [This is the link to the group webpage](http://w3fusion.ph.utexas.edu/ifs/facultystaff.html), you can get more info from their publications etc.

Happy learning :)

Comment: While this is good information I think OP was asking about crushing an ampoule using a diamond tipped projectile propelled by a conventional explosive. A form of inertial confinement - and unlikely to be much use for igniting a tokamak.

Comment: @Floris - Oh.. OK. I thought he was asking about an inverse hybrid. I misread it then. Thanks.